# How to wrap text within an image overlay

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a school project. As of this moment I am in the first steps of creating a product page. I am using an image overlay to show a description of the product while hover. My issue is the text does not wrap, it continues outside of the container. I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

```css
    .container2 {
      position: relative;
      width: 15%;
      height: 15%;
      margin-left: 50px;
        
    }
    
    .image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height:0;
      transition: .5s ease;
    }
    
    .container2:hover .overlay {
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .text {
      white-space: nowrap; 
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    .container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .column2 {
        float: center;
        margin: 20px;
        background-color: #333;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -100%;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-family: roboto;
    }
    
    .column1 {
        text-align: center;
        float: center;
        margin: 20px;
        background-color: #333;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -100%;
        color:aliceblue;
        font-family: roboto;
    }
    
    
    br {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    li {
        float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }
    
    li {
        color: darkgreen;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Shopping Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicongreen.png" />

</head>


<body>

 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="active" href="products.html">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="images/bolt2.png" width="40px" height="40px" />
  </li>

 </ul>

 <div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
  <h1>Products</h1>



  <div class="container">

   <div class="column1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
     <b>Electric Energy Electronics Product Index</b>
    </p>
    <br>




    <div class="container2">
     <img src="images/solar.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" height="50px" width="50px">
     <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">250PX Solar Panel
       <br> This solar panel is a great way to harness clean energy from the sun.</div>
     </div>




    </div>

    <div class="column2">
     Shopping cart Div

    </div>

   </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [The `word-break` CSS property specifies whether or not the browser should insert line breaks.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your css .text class with this.

```
    .text {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Please dont forget to mark my answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Freddie!! Worked Perfectly

Comment: do you happen to know how I would be able to place these div containers side by side instead of vertical?